# Django limit_choices_to on user group

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model field:

```
name = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, editable=False, limit_choices_to=   
{'is_staff': False})
```

How can I limit the choices based on a specific group of users as opposed to limiting to specific users based on a flag. Is it possible to somehow limit choices based on auth_user_groups?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can limit choices based on groups, here is one example

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, limit_choices_to= Q( groups__name = 'GroupName') )
```

try this, it works!

Answer (score 12):

For Django 1.9

`limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'My Group'}`

Comment: This is the up to date solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 limit_choices_to={'groups__pk': 2}
```